# My clock never makes it past 8 seconds

Tags: jquery, clock

So, I'm making a simple clock that just counts time from a static starting point.  The problem is, when the second mark hits 8, it resets to 0.  I can't figure out why.  Help!

Here's the clock: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/jMbem/

Here's the code for it:

HTML:

```
<h1>Mark's Busted Computer Clock</h1>
<div id="time">
    <span id="hour">146</span>:<span id="minute">45</span>:<span id="second">00</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(UpdateSecond, 1000);
});

function UpdateSecond() {
    var num = parseInt($('#second').text());
    num++;
    if (num == 60) {
        num = 0;
        UpdateMinute();
    }
    if (num < 10) {
        num = "0" + num;
    }
    $('#second').text(num);
}

function UpdateMinute() {
    var num = parseInt($('#minute').text());
    num++;
    if (num == 60) {
        num = 0;
        UpdateHour();
    }
    if (num < 10) {
        num = "0" + num;
    }
    $('#minute').text(num);
}

function UpdateHour() {
    $('#hour').text(parseInt($('#hour').text()) + 1);
}
```

Comment: Incidentally you can't rely on your interval function being called exactly every 1s. It will gradually lose time, and quickly lose time if the browser is being blocked by some slow script or plugin. You should generally store a ‘begin’ time from `new Date().getTime()`, then on each interval call look at `(new Date().getTime()-begin)/1000` to work out how many seconds have passed since the clock began.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't passing a radix to the parseInt function. Try:

```
var num = parseInt($('#minute').text(), 10);
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: any time something mysterious happens around 8, think parseInt.  :)

Comment: Fantastic! Good catch, I had no idea that was necessary.  This will be the accepted answer once I'm allowed to accept :)